# Возможно ли открыть папку на хостинге

Tags: php

Возможно ли открыть папку на хостинге через opendir()

> C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures

На локальном сервере **Open Server**
Папку открыть можно и считать файлы в ней, 
но на хостинге выдает ошибку.

Comment: Возможно.(15 символов).

Comment: Потому что на хостинге нет диска C?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Каким способом?

Comment: @u_mulder Я понимаю что его нет, вопрос был в другом.
Возможно ли открыть папку на хостинге через opendir() или через другие функции

Comment: opendir({полный путь до папки}); если вы приведете ошибку то можно будет сказать точнее в чем у вас проблема. Например неверный полный путь, или у вас нет прав на данный каталог, или хостер запретил использование этой функции.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Warning: opendir(C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /home/u30652/data/www/nilagent.ru/adm/newadmin/light/test.php on line 15
string(40) "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures"

Comment: Вот так пробуйте, и всё заработает, парой комментариев выше вам указали что диска C скорее всего там нет(что и подтвердилось) `opendir('/home/u30652/data/www/nilagent.ru/')` считайте что ваш диск C, начинается вот отсюда `/home/u30652/data/www/nilagent.ru/`, все что выше - вам не принадлежит и доступа туда у вас может не быть.

Comment: "Я понимаю что его нет", но открыть все равно попытаюсь, да?

Comment: с хостинга нельзя получить доступ к дисковому пространству на вашем компьютере. Вы можете только передать файлы с вашего пк на хостинг используя ftp, sftp или же через форму на сайте.

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Возможно я неправильно задал вопрос, остальным спасибо за уделенное время. Ответ на вопрос я получил